# Fatal error installing sails-mongo on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am trying to install https://www.npmjs.org/package/sails-mongo and it is getting 0.9.6 instead of 0.9.7 (as the latest). I have latest **node.js (0.10.25 64-bit)** and **mongodb (2.4.9 64-bit)** on Windows 7.

`C:\my_project\backend>npm install sails-mongo`

Anyways, I got fatal error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sails-mongo/0.9.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sails-mongo/0.9.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.4.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string/2.3.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.4.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string/2.3.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.9
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/0.0.3

> kerberos@0.0.3 install C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\m
ongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerbe
ros>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_
modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
  kerberos.cc
  worker.cc
  security_credentials.cc
  security_buffer.cc
  security_buffer_descriptor.cc
  security_context.cc
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocale(323): wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
Specify /EHsc [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ]
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::FunctionTemplate
          ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocale(323): wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
Specify /EHsc [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocale(323): wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
Specify /EHsc [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocale(323): wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
Specify /EHsc [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::FunctionTemplate
          ]
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(218): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ]
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(218): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::FunctionTemplate
          ]
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(218): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ]
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(218): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::FunctionTemplate
          ]
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ]
C:\Users\myname\.node-gyp\0.10.25\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C4506: no
 definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8::H
andle<T>)' [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::FunctionTemplate
          ]
  kerberos_sspi.c
  base64.c
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib' [C:\my_project\back
end\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\k
erberos.vcxproj]

> bson@0.2.5 install C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongo
db\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson>
node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modu
les\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
  bson.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocale(323): wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
Specify /EHsc [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\intrin.h(26): fa
tal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ammintrin.h': No such file or direc
tory [C:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_module
s\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
sails-mongo@0.9.6 node_modules\sails-mongo
├── async@0.2.9
├── underscore@1.4.4
├── underscore.string@2.3.1
└── mongodb@1.3.23 (kerberos@0.0.3, bson@0.2.5)
```

It's here to make it easier for you:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib' [C:\my_project\back
end\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\k
erberos.vcxproj]
```

Any idea why? And how to fix this?

**UPDATE 1:**

I followed this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2009/01/30/getting-fatal-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-kernel32-lib.aspx and it seems to fix one problem and now I got different error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sails-mongo/0.9.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sails-mongo/0.9.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.4.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string/2.3.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.9
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.4.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string/2.3.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.5

> bson@0.2.5 install c:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongo
db\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


c:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson>
node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modu
les\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  bson.cc
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocale(323): wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled.
Specify /EHsc [c:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\intrin.h(26): fa
tal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ammintrin.h': No such file or direc
tory [c:\my_project\backend\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_module
s\bson\build\bson.vcxproj]
sails-mongo@0.9.6 node_modules\sails-mongo
├── underscore@1.4.4
├── async@0.2.9
├── underscore.string@2.3.1
└── mongodb@1.3.23 (bson@0.2.5)
```

Comment: Why don't you post it in the `kerberos` module's github issues page?

Comment: I didn't feel like it's the `sails-mongo` issue. It's something on my end.

Comment: I am sure its not your fault. Looks like its trying to compile for 32 bit version of kerberos whereas you have only 64 bit version of kerberos installed on your machine. I am not very sure though.

Answer (score 2):

kerberos needs python.
Install [python for Windows](http://www.python.org/download/) and add to the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you are using correct software version ?

If you are using 64bit OS, you have to install 64bit version Node.js(x64)